# Why am I receiving these errors when installing R / RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Trying to get up and running in R and I have received some errors after installing the .exe files from CRAN and RStudio.

The installation appeared to run smoothly.

Upon running RStudio (and selecting the 64 bit version or the 32 bit version, I was told that "R was not installed".

I could get RStudio to run when I navigated directly to the 32 bit version folder (R i386). However, it appeared that code was not executing in RStudio **(UPDATE: I have figured out the problem with RStudio executing code; this was my fault. I still cannot get the 64 bit version to work)**.

When I attempted to run the 64 bit version of R directly (my machine is 64 bit, Windows 7), I receive this message:

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)".
```

I am, however, able to run the i386 version of R using the RGUI directly and execute code on it. I have restarted my machine but I have not attempted uninstall/reinstall. Would the community have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: It seems there are two issues 1) The 64 bit version of R isn't launching for you and 2) RStudio doesn't work at all.  I would suggest trying to figure out the first issue before tackling the second one.

Comment: This is general windows issue. Is it only happening with Rstudio and R?

Comment: Can you go into your 32 bit R and post the output of `Sys.info()` and `sessionInfo()`?